# SSIS Excel Destination - too many fields defined

Tags: excel, ssis

I need to create data from the flat file (word 2003) to excel 2007, using SSIS 2010. In "connection manager" screen I pick data access mode: name of the table and choose: New... In create table I have:

```
CREATE TABLE `OLE DB Destination` (
    `Column 0` NVARCHAR(50),
    `Column 1` NVARCHAR(50),
    `Column 2` NVARCHAR(50),
   .............................
`Column 1087` NVARCHAR(50)
)
```

I try "OK" and received message:

> too many fields defined. Microsoft Office Access Database Engine

My excel file has correct extension and MS OFFICE 2013 installed.
I can create only 255 columns in excel. Any ideas?

Comment: You have no options whatsoever: http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/access-2010-specifications-HA010341462.aspx Either switch to using a real database, or give up on the project.

Comment: Can you switch how you output so that data is spread between multiple Excel sheets, each with 255 columns or less?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Excel Destination's 255 column constraint appears to be a hard limit.

Possible Workarounds:

- **Split your output between multiple sheets**, each receiving less than 256 columns of data. While probably the easiest solution, it entails changing the format of your output which may or may not be acceptable.
- **Output to another format then use a Script Task or Execute Process Task to convert that other format into an Excel spreadsheet.** For example, output to CSV using a Flat File Destination then convert the output file from CSV to XLSX.
- **Use a database driver that doesn't have the 255 column limitation.** You might be able to find a third-party ODBC driver for Excel that will work with more columns.
- **Use a third-party destination component/connection manager.** For example: COZYROC's [Excel Destination](http://www.cozyroc.com/ssis/excel-destination)/[Excel Connection](http://www.cozyroc.com/ssis/excel-connection) might be able to do what you want. (Note: I've never used these and have no association with their author.)